# Flutter Android Studio Debugger Skip Framework files

Tags: android-studio, debugging, flutter

Is it possible to configure Android Studio Debugger to skip flutter framework files and packages files?
Im not interested in Step Over or Step out because for example with redux after calling dispatch I want to step skip until the reducer that I wrote, without following all the framework and package files.

Comment: what do you really mean by "skip"?

Comment: when I click 'step into' the debugger goes to the next line in code or the function in the files, so if the file is part of the framework or package then I want the debugger to skip those and stop again on one of the files that I wrote.

Comment: @Hontoni, any updates about this. I am having the same difficulty and can not figure out a way for a proper debugging.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about Android Studio but in VS Code, you just add to your user settings `settings.json` the following:

```
"dart.debugSdkLibraries": false,
"dart.debugExternalPackageLibraries": false,
```

You can get inspired by mine, or just copy [my settings.json file from gist](https://gist.github.com/tomasbaran/cd0ba7cadec4466356d1dc0faa14f1e2)

So, I guess, there should be something similar in the Android Studio Settings as well.

Comment: adding these lines in vscode launch,json doesn't work, it still goes to framework.dart

Comment: @IrfanYusanif Not to vscode launch but to VSCode user settings. Take a look at my answer again. I updated it to be clearer.

Comment: @IrfanY they renamed it to: `dart.debugExternalPackageLibraries` that's probably why it was not working for you. Now, @Danny updated the answer. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

After i added this, the debug stopped after a few step into. Nothing happened
"dart.debugSdkLibraries": false,
"dart.debugExternalLibraries": false,

Comment: Seems the same as the other answer