# Flutter debug only open/specific files (Android Studio)

Tags: flutter, dart

New to Flutter/Dart, and currently learning to debug with Android Studio (latest version Artic Fox) . When debugging I see options for: Step Over, Step Into, Step Out, Run to Cursor, etc.

When I debug, the debbugger opens new tabs with nested dart functions or classes (such as framework.dart, silver.dart, object.dart, etc). Those are not files I created, which I am not always interested on seeing them (at least for now).

I tried googling this topic, but I didn't find anything relevant. StackOverflow has a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57589509/flutter-android-studio-debugger-skip-framework-files) (2 years old), but there was no solution.

Is there an option to debug only opened or specific .dart files? At times, I am only interested in debugging open files. Plus, it takes time close all the debugger opened tabs.

Comment: I am Running into the same problem. Wondering, did you figure something out?

Answer (score 1):

I think I have figured out a solution.

The button for "Resume Program" works (default keyboard shortcut is F9 key I believe).

 [image]